# Oracle SQL: How to remove duplicate in listagg

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, listagg

After using listagg to combine my data, there are many duplicates that I want to remove.

[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CaTu.png)

There will be only 3 types of technologies in total with no specific pattern in my data. I am wondering is it possible to remove all the duplicates and only keep 1 type in the respective row?

```sql
    select
    NAME,
    RTRIM(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
            (LISTAGG(
                NVL2(Membrane_column, 'Membrane, ', NULL)
                || NVL2(SNR_column, 'SNR, ', NULL)
                || NVL2(SMR_column, 'SMR, ', NULL)
                ) within group (ORDER BY name)),
        'Membrane, |SNR, |SMR, ', '', '1', '1', 'c')
    ', ')
    as TECHNOLOGY
    from
    Table A
```

The current table I have for now

| Name | Technology |
| --- | --- |
| A | SNR, SMR, SMR, SNR |
| B | Membrane, SNR, SMR, Membrane |
| C | SMR, SMR, Membrane |

Desired Table

| Name | Technology |
| --- | --- |
| A | SNR, SMR |
| B | Membrane, SNR, SMR |
| C | SMR, Membrane |

Comment: what is the desired output ?

Comment: Done. Sorry for not being clear with the outpot.

Comment: Please, post your source data as text, not as image. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557)

Comment: idk why i keep getting error when posting the table. that is why I posted the image instead

Comment: Please post it as plain text or whatever that can be copied, someone will edit it. Image is not useful at all (it is really boring to type all the data manually).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe just create the SUM of the SNR/SMR/Membrane columns, group them by name, and replace the numbers with the strings that you want to see in the output.

Query (first step ...)

```
select name
, sum( snr_column ), sum( smr_column ), sum( membrane_column ) 
from original 
group by name
;

-- output
NAME    SUM(SNR_COLUMN)     SUM(SMR_COLUMN)     SUM(MEMBRANE_COLUMN)
2       1                   1                   2
3       null                2                   1
1       2                   2                   null
```

Replace the sums, concatenate, remove the trailing comma with RTRIM()

```
select 
  name 
, rtrim( 
     case when sum( snr_column ) >= 1 then 'SNR, ' end
  || case when sum( smr_column ) >= 1 then 'SMR, ' end 
  || case when sum( membrane_column ) >= 1 then 'Membrane' end 
  , ' ,'
  ) as technology
from original 
group by name
order by name
;
-- output
NAME    TECHNOLOGY
1       SNR, SMR
2       SNR, SMR, Membrane
3       SMR, Membrane
```

Code the CASEs in the required order.
[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=079cba00c8695c8e4a8c629036077a7c)

Comment: You save my day! This works! Haha. Thank you so much. Was cracking my head to understand how does the regexp_replace works for days while there is actually a much simple solution! :)

Answer (score 4):

This could be an easy way:

```
select name, listagg(technology, ', ') within group (order by 1) -- or whatever order you need
from 
(
  select distinct name, technology
  from tableA
)
group by name
```

Comment: Thanks anyway. but not what i want. added in the desired output in the original post!

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Oracle 19c [`listagg`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466) supports `distinct` keyword. Also `within group` became optional.

```
with a as ( 
  select column_value as a 
  from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C')) q 
) 
select listagg(distinct a, ',') 
from a

LISTAGG(DISTINCTA,',')
----------------------
A,B,C
```

livesql example [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:43:6827222235223::NO:::&success_msg=U2NyaXB0ICZxdW90O0xJU1RBR0cmcXVvdDsgc2F2ZWQu%2FsvhF3xCe320lZ68H8XC_gxw36NrXzHGjh7mia55vVCTdcFz00Y6Nm17yetHkENyb7O0ITE-NA0uz1FleCQf60Q).

Comment: Thanks anyway. but not what i want. added in the desired output in the original post!

Comment: if you are using Oracle 19c, this answer is what you are looking for. But that is the key point, it only works on 19c onwards